# How to set a checkbox's checked-attribute via its changed-eventlistener

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material2

I have a matrix in angular.js 4 (with material.angular) which is filled with checkboxes. When the user clicks a checkbox, a HTTP-Request is send to backend server. In case the backend server is not available or the service call goes wrong for any reason, I want the checkbox to return to it's previous state (checked/unchecked). Therefore I implemented the following change-eventhandler to make the service call and react dependent on the result of the service call:

```
zuordnungChanged(rolle_id: string, recht_id: string) {
let a = this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id];
if (a === true ){
  this.rechtematrix.rechtEntziehen(rolle_id, recht_id).subscribe(() => {
      a = false;
      this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id] = a;
      //Notify user
      });
    },
    () => {
      //Notify user
    });
} else {
  this.rechtematrix.rechtVergeben(rolle_id, recht_id).subscribe(() => {
      a = true;
      this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id] = a;
      //Notify User
      });
  },
    () => {
      //Notify user
    }
  );
}
}
```

The *zuordnungsmatrix* variable is defined and filled like that:

```
private zuordnungen: Array<any>;
  private zuordnungsmatrix = [];

erstelleZuordnungsmatrix(): void {
    for (let rolle of this.zuordnungen) {
      for ( let recht of rolle.recht_ids) {
        this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle.rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht] = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

I bound  the values from *zuordnungsmatrix* to the checkbox' checked-attribute like this:

```
<table td-data-table *ngIf="rechteUndRollenVorhanden()">
      <tr>
        <th td-data-table-column></th>
      <th td-data-table-column *ngFor="let rolle of rollen" [id]="'Rolle_' + rolle.rolle_id">{{rolle.beschreibung}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr td-data-table-row *ngFor="let recht of rechte" [id]="'Recht_' + recht.recht_id">
        <td td-data-table-cell>{{recht.beschreibung}}</td>
        <td td-data-table-cell *ngFor="let rolle of rollen">
          <md-checkbox [id]="'Rolle_' + rolle.rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht.recht_id"
                       [checked]="zuordnungsmatrix['Rolle_' + rolle.rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht.recht_id] ? true : false"
                        (change)="zuordnungChanged(rolle.rolle_id, recht.recht_id, $event)">{{zuordnungsmatrix['Rolle_' + rolle.rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht.recht_id] ? true : false}}
          </md-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

My problem know is that I don't know how to let the checkboxes represent the actual state of *zuordnungsmatrix*. The variable is updated and this binding in the view works as well:

```
{{zuordnungsmatrix['Rolle_' + rolle.rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht.recht_id] ? true : false}}
```

But I tried a lot to update the checkbox but It didn't work. Anyway, the initial setting of the checkbox' checked-state works fine. How can I update a checkbox' state in its own event listener?

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D ?

Comment: Yeah I have but the documentation you posted is for angular < 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:

For some reason Angular doesn't update the changed value of the checkbox via One-Way-Binding. You simply have to explicit set the `checked` status . To do that you can pass the event from HTML to the component via the parameter `$event`. This is already done in the example above.

In the change event handler in the component you can read the event and get a reference to the checkbox element. All you have to do then is setting the checked attribute of this element (`$event.source.checked`).
The event handler from the question now looks like this:

```
zuordnungChanged(rolle_id: string, recht_id: string, event: any) {
    let a = this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id];
    if (a === true ){
      this.rechtematrix.rechtEntziehen(rolle_id, recht_id).subscribe(() => {
          //Happy case
          a = false;
          this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id] = a;
          //Notify user
          });
        },
        () => {
          //Bad case
          event.source.checked = this.zuordnungsmatrix['Rolle_' + rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht_id];
          //Notify user
        });
    } else {
      this.rechtematrix.rechtVergeben(rolle_id, recht_id).subscribe(() => {
          //Happy case
          a = true;
          this.zuordnungsmatrix["Rolle_" + rolle_id + "_Recht_" + recht_id] = a;
          //Notify User
          });
      },
        () => {
          //Bad case
          event.source.checked = this.zuordnungsmatrix['Rolle_' + rolle_id + '_Recht_' + recht_id];
          //Notify user
        }
      );
    }
}
```

Note that the attribute setting is only done, when the REST-call fails. This is because in happy case the checkbox is updated automatically by user interaction.